# How to call my web scraper from within an express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a web scraper in the root of my Nodejs server, running express. It's a file that uses needle to make the get requests for the html and it returns an Array of data. Then I have my index.js with my express routes, a simple one like `"/api/scrape"`.

However when I go to that url, the servers console will still print out a console.log in the scraper to indicate that it's finishing. But express wants to move on before waiting for the scraper to finish.

How can I wait for the scraper to finish before sending the response back to React.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting your function which calls the web scraper to an async function, and have express call the function with await. That way, express will wait for a promise to be returned, instead of moving forward.

I believe this is also achievable in express, by placing it as a middleware:

```
const example_scrape = (req, res, next) => {
... do your scraping
next() //allows express to move onto the next route? not sure the terminology 
}


app.get('/api/scrape_my_site', example_scrape, (req,res) => {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this project - https://github.com/vodolaz095/email-parser-api.

it is simple Selenium powered api, that is called from nodejs application exposing sort of REST API.

code is simple

Here is expressjs router code that actually calls scraper in response to POST request

https://github.com/vodolaz095/email-parser-api/blob/master/index.js#L21-L53

Here is scraper code

https://github.com/vodolaz095/email-parser-api/blob/master/lib/parser.js